# how to animate a draggable element in center of another element jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I want want to animate a draggable div to the center of another div. how can i do this? In fact here I want to drag div.drag to the edge of div.fix and after that want the element to go to the center of div.fix. thank you for your help

```js
            $(document).ready(function() {
                var widthFix = $(".fix").width() / 2;
                var HeightFix = $(".fix").height() / 2;
                var widthDrag = $(".drag").width() / 2;
                var HeightDrag = $(".drag").height() / 2;
                console.log(`x:${widthFix} y:${HeightFix}`);
    
                var distanceTop = $(".fix").offset().top;
                var distanceLeft = $(".fix").offset().left;
                console.log(distanceTop + " " + distanceLeft);
                $(".drag").mousedown(function() {
                    $(window).on("mousemove", function(e) {
                        var x = e.pageX;
                        var y = e.pageY;
                        $(".drag").css({
                            top: y,
                            left: x,
                            transform: "translate(-50%,-50%)"
                        });
    
                        if (x >= distanceLeft && y >= distanceTop) {
                            // alert("you loose");
    
                            $(".drag").animate({
    
                                left: HeightFix - HeightDrag,
                                top: widthFix - widthDrag,
    
                            }, 1000, "linear", function() {});
    
                        }
                    });

                $(".drag").mouseup(function() {


                    $(window).off("mousemove")

                });


            });

        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <div class="drag"></div>
        <div class="fix"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JQuery UI [draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/) and [droppable](https://jqueryui.com/droppable/) and write your task on drop event.

```
$('#drag').draggable();
$('#fix').droppable({
accept:'#drag',
drop:function(event,ui){
//now get the draggable element using ui object and set the style you want.
}
});
```